# QGIS R Script - Unicode Error

Tags: qgis, r, zonal-statistics

I am working with QGIS 3.32.0-Lima on Windows 11.
I am trying to port an R script to QGIS by creating an R script (https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/appendices/qgis_r_syntax.html).

However, when I run it, I get an encoding error that I can't understand:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last): File
 "C:\Users/giano/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\SGI/python/plugins\processing_r\processing\algorithm.py",
 line 396, in processAlgorithm output =
 RUtils.execute_r_algorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback) File
 "C:\Users/giano/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\SGI/python/plugins\processing_r\processing\utils.py",
 line 281, in execute_r_algorithm for line in
 iter(proc.stdout.readline, ''): File
 "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\codecs.py", line 322, in decode (result,
 consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
 UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe8 in position
 21: invalid continuation byte Execution failed after 37.93 seconds
```

The code I am using is as follows, and I have two input rasters, one with Integer values and the other is float.

In fact, the objective is to perform zonal statistics between rasters by calculating the median of the values of raster A for each class of raster B (which the "Raster Layer Zonal statistics" tool does not do) and then reclassify the values of raster A based on the calculated value.

```
##My scripts=group

##LC=raster
##issue=raster
##output= output raster

library(raster)
library(sf)
library(sp)

x<-resample(issue,LC, method='ngb')
issue <-x

issue <- crop(issue, extent(LC))  
res(issue) <- res(LC)
extent(issue) <- extent(LC)
 
s<- issue
r<- LC
result <- zonal(s, r, 'median')

r2 <- reclassify(r, result)


rc <- function(x) {
 
  x1 <- x[1]  ##valore pixel della prima banda
  x2 <- x[2] ##valore pixel 2 banda
  ifelse(x1 <=  x2, 0,
  ifelse(x1 >  x2, 1, NA)) }

s2 <- stack(s,r2)

beginCluster(6) ##ASSIGN CORE
z1 <- clusterR(s2, calc, args=list(fun=rc))
endCluster()


output<- z1
```

Has anyone experienced similar encoding issues or R script problems in QGIS?

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from a line in the processing code that is reading each line of the R script file. The R script file must be a UTF-8 encoded file. The python code encounters a byte of hexadecimal value 0xe8 in the script code, which at that point in the line does not make a valid UTF-8 encoded character, so it stops.

Its not possible to see which line of the R script is causing the problem, but we do know its at "position 21" in the line (starting from 0 because python starts at 0) from the error message.

Also, 0xe8 is a valid character in other encodings - for example in the latin-1 encoding it is an "e" with an acute accent. But Python here can only accept UTF-8 encodings.

Then I notice your script has comments that are not in English:

```
x1 <- x[1]  ##valore pixel della prima banda
x2 <- x[2] ##valore pixel 2 banda
```

and the "e" in "valore" here is in position 21 in the line. If this is actually a latin-1 encoded R file with an accented "e" (represented in the file by the byte 0xe8) then that explains the error (but does not totally explain why it doesn't look like an accented "e" here, perhaps StackOverflow has sanitised it because its not UTF-8).

So.....:

- Edit any non-plain A-Z letters out of the file and see if it works.
- That solves the problem, the future solution is to make sure you only use UTF-8 encoded files
- Recoding files from one encoding to another is possible, but depends on your platform so I can't give guidance here.